# Writting an Equation inside a Subfigure

Tags: floats, equations, subfloats

I am making a big figure with subfigure for the "180 seconds thesis" challenge.

My problem is that in order to include my equation, I had to make a screenshot of it and insert the pdf of the equation. The issue with this method is that it is a bit blurry in the final document. Therefore, I would like to know if I could write the equation inside the figure.

The complete code, which is working, is this :

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,height=0.20\textheight]{Piggybank.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth,height=0.5\textheight]{exampletasklatex.pdf}

\begin{subfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth, height =.25\textheight]{multihistcmpl40.pdf}  
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}
  \centering\raisebox{3ex}{
  \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth, height =.10\textheight]{equation.pdf}}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}
  \centering\raisebox{-0.5ex}{
  \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth, height =.25\textheight]{multihisthondcmpl40.pdf}} 
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

However, I would like to replace

```
\begin{subfigure}
  \centering\raisebox{3ex}{
  \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth, height =.10\textheight]{equation.pdf}}
\end{subfigure}
```

By writing directly the equation inside the subfigure, which code is :

```
\begin{equation}
  U(c_t,c_{t+k}) = \frac{1}{\alpha} (c_t - \omega_1)^\alpha + \delta^k\frac{1}{\alpha}(c_{t+k} - \omega_2)^\alpha,
\end{equation}
```

Can someone help me understand how to do it ? Internet explains how to put Image inside Equations, not how to put Equations inside Images.

Comment: Did you try it? If so what was the result?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete/compilable small document. From code can be concluded that you use obsolete `subfigure` package ...

Comment: One solution may to to make a Tikz graphic, and then you can include this at a position and then overlay an equation at another position over the figure. Using Tikz would allow you a degree of fine tuning over the position. Might be worth trying out.

Comment: Please, provide a sketch, how your figure should be. Your fragment code generate a figure, which is to height that can be placed on page. BTW, you can simply replace equation image with equation code. What is actually the problem?

Comment: You can put the equation in a `minipage`.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you have provided the complete code but it is missing vital elements like the `\documentclass` and what packages you have used. I have had to spend time trying to generate an MWE of your problem when I have had other things to do. --- GOM

```
% subfigeqprob.tex  SE 542448

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

In text:
\begin{equation}
  U(c_t,c_{t+k}) = \frac{1}{\alpha} (c_t - \omega_1)^\alpha + \delta^k\frac{1}{\alpha}(c_{t+k} - \omega_2)^\alpha,
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
\begin{equation}
  U(c_t,c_{t+k}) = \frac{1}{\alpha} (c_t - \omega_1)^\alpha + \delta^k\frac{1}{\alpha}(c_{t+k} - \omega_2)^\alpha,
\end{equation}
\caption{An equation}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.75\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
  U(c_t,c_{t+k}) = \frac{1}{\alpha} (c_t - \omega_1)^\alpha + \delta^k\frac{1}{\alpha}(c_{t+k} - \omega_2)^\alpha,
\end{equation}
\caption{In subfigure}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This shows three placements of your equation: in the running text, in a `figure` and in a `subfigure`. In each case the equation is typeset.

Of course I might be completely wrong about the class and package but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

From your figure code fragment can be concluded:

- Generated figure is to big that can be fit in text area on the page.
- You use obsolete package `subfigure`, which is repaced with `sibfig` which define `\subfloats` command for placing sub images in figure.
- In your case seems to be better to use `subcaption` package, which define `subfigure` environment with prescribed width. Its behavior is similar to behavior of `\minipage`.
- Your equation is quite wide, so it can not be fit between neighborhood sub-images. I suggest to use instead `equation` environment `\multline` defined in the `asmmath` package.

A possible MWE (Minimal Working Example) based on guessing can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document remove option "demo"
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \setkeys {Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth, height=0.3\textheight]{Piggybank.pdf}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth, height=0.3\textheight]{exampletasklatex.pdf}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.22\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[height =.25\textheight]{multihistcmpl40.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.55\linewidth}
\begin{multline}
  U(c_t,c_{t+k}) = \frac{1}{\alpha} (c_t - \omega_1)^\alpha\\ 
    + \delta^k\frac{1}{\alpha}(c_{t+k} - \omega_2)^\alpha,
\end{multline}
    \end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.22\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height =.25\textheight]{multihisthondcmpl40.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

Note: I change image size  so, that the figures cen be fit inside text area.